# How to write sql select in order to obtain percentage

Tags: sql-server, select, percentage

I define a view which contains 2 columns

```
France    Wine 
France    Fromage
France    Meat
France    Chips
Belgium   Bier
Belgium   Chips  
Belgium   Chocolate
```

i love Bier and Chips
which select in order to obtain the best country
like

```
Belgium 66%
France  25%
```

Comment: Hi Fred, I also like Beer and Chips! Any problems in particular that you run into with making this query? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

You want the count for Bier and Chips for each country, divided by the total item count for each country.

The count for Bier and Chips goes something like this:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN Item IN ('Bier', 'Chips') THEN 1 END)
```

If `Item` is Bier or Chips, the `CASE` returns `1`, which is counted. If it's not Bier or Chips, the `CASE` returns a NULL, which is not counted.

Putting it all together:

```
SELECT
  Country,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN Item IN ('Bier', 'Chips') THEN 1 END) /
      CAST(COUNT(*) AS NUMERIC)
    AS BierChipsPercent
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Country
```

Why the `CAST(COUNT(*) AS NUMERIC)`? Because without it, SQL Server appears to be treating both COUNTs as integer so it's truncating the result when they're divided. Casting to NUMERIC makes it behave, so 1/4 will yield 0.25 instead of zero.

The above query will give you:

```
Belgium 0.6666666666
France  0.25
```

To get the percentage, just multiply by 100. To get whole numbers, apply the ROUND() function:

```
SELECT
  Country,
  ROUND(
      COUNT(CASE WHEN Item IN ('Bier', 'Chips') THEN 1 END) /
      CAST(COUNT(*) AS NUMERIC) * 100, 0)
    AS BierChipsPercent
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Country
```

This will give you:

```
Belgium 67
France  25
```

Note that Belgium's percentage rounds up to 67. If you want it to be 66, use `FLOOR` instead of `ROUND`.

There's a SQL Fiddle for this [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9cd5e/7).

Comment: It doesn't work for me with sqlserver, SELECT c1,
      ROUND(COUNT(CASE WHEN c2 IN ('Bier', 'Chips') THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) * 100, 0) AS BierChipsPercent FROM myTable GROUP BY c1

Comment: Sorry about that - I just realized the SQL Fiddle, which I tested with, was set to MySQL. In SQL Server it looks like the `COUNT` is treated as an integer, so the division result is getting truncated. I've updated my answer so it will work correctly in SQL Server. The SQLFiddle link at the bottom of my answer now points to a SQL Server fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This is my select but I understood that I can also write with over() ???

```
SELECT  c1 ,
convert(
        decimal(5,2),
        100.00 * 
        (select COUNT(*) from myTable WHERE c1=t.c1 and (c2='Chips' or c2='Bier')) 
        /
        (SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE c1=t.c1)
        ) AS percentage

  FROM myTable t
  group by c1

 c1         percentage
 Belgium    66.67
 France     25.00
```